react select library select component take first value as select option default in tab press navigation case
when we use react select in our project and we navigate or focus on it using tab at that time drop down menu is open than next when we press tab key and navigate to other component at that time it is take first value of drop down take as select value solve my issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Recently, I came across another React select component
"select-paginated"
that you might find helpful.
